# Python program needs newer version of libX11

Tags: python, shared-libraries, x11

I'm trying to use a python application for remote visualization on Centos 7 and I get this:
`ImportError: /lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_poll_for_reply64`
 
As far as I understand this is related to that symbol being included in newer versions of libX11.so.6 with respect to the one shipped with Centos 7. Is there any chance I can get this working by building a new version of libX11 and placing it in, say, may $HOME/local/lib folder? Or do I need to build the entire X11 server? How do I tell the program to use that specific version of the library?